# Looping an object to preLoad a list of images

Tags: javascript

I have an object which carries images that i want to preLoad before i display them.

The info is stored like so:

```
 //var data =     ["images",{"ground":["0.png"]}]
```

I then want to loop them with an onLoad to be sure they are loaded so they will display... how ever they do not display on the first frame.... and im sure its because of the onLoad check.

This is what i have:

```
function preLoad(data){
    gfx = new Array();
    count = 0;
    for(var i in data[1]){
        if (data[1].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            ++count;

            gfx[i] = new Array();
            for(var j in data[1][i]){
                tmp = new Image();
                    tmp.onload = function(){
                        tmp.src = data[0]+'/'+data[1][i][j];
                        gfx[i].push(tmp);               
                }
            }           
        }   
    }

    window.gph = gfx;

    main();
}
```

Have i got this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

a) copy to the array inside the onload but
b) load the src outside the onload AFTER assigning onload

```
for(var j in data[1][i]){
  tmp = new Image();
  tmp.onload = function(){
    gfx[i].push(tmp);               
  }
  tmp.src = data[0]+'/'+data[1][i][j];
}
```

lastly it is common practice to use o or obj for a var in a for in and i in a normal for loop
as in

```
for(var o in data[1])
```

and

```
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
```

the whole thing smells a little, with no var for the gfx which you then copy to a windows scoped var

How about

```
function preLoad(obj){
  var data = obj[1], path=obj[0],tmp;
  window.gph = {};
  for(var o in data){
    if (data[o].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      gph[o] = [];
      for(var p in data[o]){
        tmp = new Image();
        tmp.onload = function(){
          gph[o].push(tmp);               
        }
        tmp.src = path+'/'+data[o][p];
      }           
    }   
  }
  main();
}
```

Comment: Your suggested code didn't seem to create the objects for the images to gph?

Comment: Fixed. I missed renaming gpx

Answer (score 0):

try assigning the src attribute before the onload event, not in it:

```
for(var j in data[1][i]){
    tmp = new Image();
    tmp.src = data[0]+'/'+data[1][i][j];
    tmp.onload = function(){
        gfx[i].push(tmp);               
    }
}
```